# I'm getting following error while using node.js with socketstream."throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + x + "'")"

Tags: node.js, socketstream

I'm using node.js with socketstream..I'm getting following error while running my

"appln.Cannot find module '/entry'
[Break On This Error]

throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + x + "'")

```
           NewNodeProject
 client
   -code
      -app
      -libs 
   -css
      -libs
 static
 templates
 views
   -app.html
 node_modules
   -express
   -socketstream
 server
   -rpc
      -user.js
   -app.js
```

Comment: Hi Maaaaani, did you generate that project using 'socketstream new <project_name>'? It looks like you're missing an entry.js file at /client/code/app/entry.js

Comment: @paulbjensen : no i didn't generate the project using 'socketstream new <project_name>'.ok i will try that.

Comment: @paulbjensen:thanks.now my application is working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use SocketStream's generator to generate the application folders and files, so that no files/folders are accidentally missed out:

```
socketstream new <project_name>
```

You can pass the following flags with this command:

```
-c    (use CoffeeScript versions of the application's files)
-m    (generate the application without the demo code files)
-j    (use jade's templating system for the view & template files)
```